# Remove empty input field values, shown as dots in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, html-table

Please can you help me with my code?

```
function tabelleFuellen(eingabeFeldArray) {
    for (var eingabeFeldZaehler = 0; eingabeFeldZaehler < eingabeFeldArray.length; eingabeFeldZaehler++)
    {
        document.cookie += eingabeFeldArray[eingabeFeldZaehler].value + "|";
    }  

    document.cookie += "~";
    $('#tableinsert tbody').remove();
    var zeilenArray = document.cookie.split('~');
    for (var zeilenZaehler = 0; zeilenZaehler < zeilenArray.length - 1; zeilenZaehler++)
    {
        var spaltenArray = zeilenArray[zeilenZaehler].split('|');
        document.getElementById("tableinsert").innerHTML += "<tbody><tr><td>" + spaltenArray[0] + "</td><td>" + spaltenArray[1] + "</td><td>" + spaltenArray[2] + "</td><td>" + spaltenArray[3] + "<td>" + spaltenArray[4] + "</td></tr></tbody>";
    }

    $('.field1').val('');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var eingabeFeldArray = $('.field1');
        tabelleFuellen(eingabeFeldArray);
    });
}
```

This code takes value from input fields, saves them into a cookie and writes  down into a table. But if the input fields are empty the table will always make a new row with a dot.

How to remove these dots?

Comment: `:empty{display:none;}` will help you.

Comment: that doesnt solve my problem at all :(